# Daemon after update to v0.13.0.3 gives ERROR output

Tags: daemon

I'm getting the following error in the daemon after the update:

> 2018-10-17
>   23:36:03.705  [RPC1]  ERROR   cn  src/cryptonote_basic/cryptonote_format_utils.cpp:185    Failed
>   to parse transaction from blob

Everything appears to be fine except this error is in red. All of the google searches tell me something is possibly wrong with the blockchain database locally but I *just* updated and everything seems fine.

Answer (score 1):

This is a known bug to do with wallet/daemon communication when the wallet tries to read the txpool. It is fixed on github (https://github.com/monero-project/monero/pull/4636), and will be fixed in 0.13.0.4 soon.

It does not mean your blockchain is corrupted, and you do not need to resync it or otherwise fix it. Either apply the patch above if you can, or wait for 0.13.0.4.